# Regex match common websites URL

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex

I have a component that I want to use for forms and it's for `websites`. However, there are multiple possible patterns:

- https://www.website.com
- http://www.website.com
- [www.website.com](http://www.website.com)

**Question:**

How can I set the pattern for the input to account for these possible URL patterns?

**Component.tsx:**

```
<Form.Control
  type="url"
  placeholder="Website"
  pattern="https?://.*"
  onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setValue((event.target.value).toLowerCase())}
  maxLength={100}
/>
```

Comment: Do you want to support other formats of URLs - other protocols, custom ports, username included, paths, etc?

Comment: Any research on how to validate a URL address using RegExp?

Comment: I'm trying to cover the bases of most general urls (https://, http://, www.)

Comment: How will it be used?

Comment: `www` is not necessary. `https://example.com` for example

Comment: It's a form for a client, so there's a possibility they would enter something like www.website.com or maybe copy a url which will most likely have http:// or https://

Answer (score 2):

For some **basic websites URL matching**  you could:

```
^(https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+\.\w+$
```

Which will match:

```
https://www.website.com  
http://www.website.com  
http://website.com  
http://www.com           (yep, that's a valid website)
www.website.com
```

but not

```
https://website
http://.com
website.com
www.com
website
```

"basic" because of the `\S+` part just ensures the Domain has no whitespace characters.

[Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/R6np9V/2)

Comment: Hmmm this seems to work, but not for `www.website.com`

Comment: Am I missing anything in my Regex pattern or the formatting of it? `pattern="^(https?:\/\/|www\.).+\.\w+$"`

Comment: @jefelewis see [this Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R6np9V/2) the address is matched as expected. Are you sure you don't have any leading or trailing spaces?